# How to Reuse a locally defined element under the Same Parent Tag

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation

Why Does not 'ref' work in this case :

```
<xs:complexType name="Team">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="Size">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                    <xs:totalDigits value="1"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element ref="Size"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The element Size has local scope , Can't it be reused locally?

Edit:The above case may not make much sense.Consider the Case below , is there no way to reuse the existing definition of "Size":

```
<xs:complexType name="Team">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="Size">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                    <xs:totalDigits value="1"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="teamLeads">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="Size"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only reference top-level elements.

> {term}    The (top-level) element declaration ·resolved· to by the ·actual value· of the `ref` [attribute].

http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#declare-element (see the last section in the box)

Comment: Usually in other programming languages , local elements can be used in their complete scope.XML local elements don't work that way?

Comment: No, they don't.  You make a nice point - they could have made it work that way, but didn't. If you're not sure what they decided, please check the *element declaration* section of the spec I linked to. :-)  BTW: local declarations are local to their complex type - so in your second example, the two Sizes are in different symbol spaces. http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#concepts-nameSymbolSpaces (3rd para) `Every complex type definition defines its own local attribute and element declaration symbol spaces, where these symbol spaces are distinct from each other`

Answer (score 1):

`Why Does not 'ref' work in this case`

Because you are trying to define same element twice. Even if you don't use ref but name it will error out!

It is as good as declaring element twice like this:

example:

```
<xs:complexType name="Team">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="Size">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                    <xs:totalDigits value="1" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Size">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                    <xs:totalDigits value="1" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
     </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

A ComplexType cannot have element of same name with same or different type multiple times defined..
`Warning    : Elements with the same name and in the same scope must have the same type.`

This might be the reason for the error you are getting.. The message may not be clear but the reason is same.

**Edit:** In situations like this, we use maxOccurs, which does the job! 

 If you want to use ref then corresponding element should be in different XSD (imported via namespace) or atleast outside current ComplexType

**With the same name there can be multiple elements in the different hierarchy! of different type** !! XSD allows this! and it has to allow! 
And When you use ref with this name, which element should it consider?? it will become an ambiguous definition! isn't it?

**This is the reason**, XSD doesn't allow non-global elements as ref.. Though your current code doesn't have multiple elements with same name, **it can have** .. 
 Here is the example for multiple elements at different hierarchy with different types:

```
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="Size">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
          <xs:totalDigits value="1" />
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="something">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Size" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <!--<xs:element ref="Size" />-->
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: "ref" does not mean declaration of an element , it means referring to a previous declaration,right?
So , in my initial code I am just trying to refer to that existing element.What went wrong then?

Comment: not declaration but specification! it's like having a type defined somewhere else and using it in current place! Ultimately you are forcing `Size` to be appearing two times! (ofcourse with same type!) which is not welcome as per XSD rules. Rather maxOccurs is more suitable here ..

Comment: I agree that `ref` is not a declaration but ultimate result for both your try and the example I have provided end up as same!

Comment: `If you want to use ref then corresponding element should be in different XSD (imported via namespace) or atleast outside current ComplexType` that means on `(top-level) element declaration` as mentioned in the link provided by 13ren

Comment: Well , I understand that it works for globally declared elements.But my question is since its a locally declared element why can't it be referenced in the local scope?

Comment: I guess you can relate its working as same as of `ComplexType` or `SimpleType` .. where you can declare a ComplexType/SimpleType with a name(ofcourse as global) and reuse it as type for different elements ..

Comment: And you can't use complexType/simpleType as type for other elements if it lies under another element .. like the way you have defined `simpleType` for element `size`.. It's a rule of XSD! XSD doesn't even allow you to declare a name for complexType or simpleType if they aren't global!

Comment: So the thumb rule is simple! If you want to reuse something declare it globally!

Comment: Well , I take the simpleType or ComplexType inside elements as ANONYMOUS.Since they don't have any name ; they can't be used anywhere.but the element "Size" does have a name.

Comment: And **with the same name there can be multiple elements in the different hierarchy! of different type** !! XSD allows this! and it has to allow! When you use `ref` with this name, which element should it consider?? it will become an ambiguous definition! isn't it? This is the reason, XSD doesn't allow non-global elements as ref.. Though your current code doesn't have multiple elements with same name, **it can have**

Comment: You don't face this `multiple definitions issue` ! when you declare something globally! because you can't have duplicate definitions with same name! So the parser will easily know and identify which is the element or definition you are pointing to.

Comment: Added an example in the answer.. edited as per the discussions made in Comments.

Comment: Usually in programming Languages , the local element takes more preference over the global element with the same name.Why not the Same in xml?

Comment: **programming language**?? XSD isn't a programming language! it's a declarative language! It has got its own set of rules! And **I told you the reason, why it doesn't allow!** And you should not treat the element declarations like Local variables! they are not! And it is not like you can't achieve what you have been looking for but the methodology you are following is WRONG (as per rules of XSD)!

Comment: Well , My bad.Okay , its a declarative Language but Rules are  always based on some Reasons.Anyways , Thanks a lot for Your answers!:)

Comment: Yes! and the rule is XSD allows same name to be used in different hierarchy that means, at different hierarchy it can have different types! In realtime world, this happens! Let's take an example of table. Once in your XML you define Table as a wooden table with four legs. And once as an HTML table with Rows and Columns. Imagine if you declare some element with ref as 'Table' which table should parser refer to? Because both HTML table and Wooden table are having same name and (assume) both are local to this new element!

Comment: Just to allow local declaration to be reused, we cannot restrict XML saying it should not have same name of tags multiple times with multiple types! On the other hand if you know that HTML table is most occurring element in your XML, then you can declare an element globally and in both the places you can use it with `ref` attribute! Hope you find it useful now.

Comment: Well, in the cases of multiple declarations in different hierarchies , Can't the local element be given the preference as is done in programming languages(Ofcourse XMl is a declarative one :) ).

Comment: How does a parser know which one is Local? actually, there is nothing called local declaration exist in XSD concept! It's just for convention we are using global and local.. so the element that you declare under a complexType or another element is not a kind of variable that is declared! but it's a part of declaration (of it's parent).. on the other hand reusable definitions are placed as top entity, and used as token!

Comment: let me clarify you this: 1. What you are considering as LOCAL DECLARATION isn't actually valid! because! with so called LOCAL-DECLARATION! you are trying to define two elements with same name and same type under same parent! which is not allowed per XSD's basic rules of declaration (This has been discussed already)

Comment: 2. If an element is declared under a ComplexType, it's not a actually a token that can be reused! but part of declaration of its parent! its like `this` element has to appear under `this` complexType!